# SwiftUI: @Environment not receiving provided value down the view hierarchy

Tags: swiftui, environment

I am following the example of [this project](https://github.com/nalexn/clean-architecture-swiftui) to create my iOS app (thanks Alexey!), but can't get the @Environment variable to receive the value that is being passed down the UI hierarchy. The top level view receives the correct value, but the downstream view receives the `default` value.

EDIT: After tying to replicate Asperi's code, I found that this behavior happens only when the downstream view is invoked via a `NavigationLink`. Updated the code below:

EDIT2: The problem was with where the `environment` method was being invoked. Invoking it on the `NavigationView` instead of the `MainView` solved the problem. Code updated below:

#### Custom Environment key - `DIContainer`

```
struct DIContainer: EnvironmentKey {
    
    let interactor: Interactor
    
    init(interactor: Interactor) {
        self.interactor = interactor
    }
    
    static var defaultValue: Self { Self.default }
    
    private static let `default` = Self(interactor: .stub)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var injected: DIContainer {
        get { self[DIContainer.self] }
        set { self[DIContainer.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

#### `App` struct

```
private let container: DIContainer

init() {
    container = DIContainer(interactor: RealInteractor())
}

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            MainView()
        }
        .environment(\.injected, container)
}
```

#### Main View

```
struct MainView: View {

    @Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer
    // `injected` has the `RealInteractor`, as expected

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Main: \(injected.foo())")  \\ << Prints REAL

            NavigationLink(destination: SearchView()) {
                Text("Search")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Search View

```
struct SearchView: View {

    @Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer
    // `injected` has the `StubInteractor`, why?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Search: \(injected.foo())")
    }
}
```

I am able to solve this problem by modifying the `MainView` like so:

```
    var body: some View {
        SearchView()
            .environment(\.injected, container)
    }
```

But isn't avoiding doing this repeatedly the purpose of `@Environment`?

Any guidance/pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've tryied to replicate all parts and to make them compiled... and the result just works as expected - environment is passed down the view hierarchy, so you might miss something in your real code.

Here is complete module, tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
class Interactor {                    // << replicated !!
    static let stub = Interactor()
    func foo() -> String { "stub" }
}

class RealInteractor: Interactor {             // << replicated !!
    override func foo() -> String { "real" }
}

struct ContentView: View {                  // << replicated !!
    private let container: DIContainer

    init() {
        container = DIContainer(interactor: RealInteractor())
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainView()
        }
        .environment(\.injected, container) // << to affect any links !!
    }
}

// no changes in env parts
struct DIContainer: EnvironmentKey {

    let interactor: Interactor

    init(interactor: Interactor) {
        self.interactor = interactor
    }

    static var defaultValue: Self { Self.default }

    private static let `default` = Self(interactor: .stub)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var injected: DIContainer {
        get { self[DIContainer.self] }
        set { self[DIContainer.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    @Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer
    // `injected` has the `RealInteractor`, as expected

    var body: some View {
        SearchView()
    }
}


// just tested here
struct SearchView: View {

    @Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer

    var body: some View {
        Text("Result: \(injected.interactor.foo())")     // << works fine !!
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Wow! Didn't expect such due diligence from anyone. Thanks! After I tried to replicate-back your working environment, I found that my `SearchView` was being invoked in a `NavigationLink` and that causes the problem.

Comment: Invoking `environment` method on the `NavigationView` solved my problem. Can you update your answer for future coders and I can accept it?